# Install matlibplot widget plugin on Ubuntu Qtdesigner4

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, plugins, pyqt, qt-designer

On the python distribution for windows, winpython, there is an additional pyqt widget plugin for Qt designer called matplotlib. Unfortunately, Qtdesigner installed with winpython will not run on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (my OS), so I cannot have this plugin installed by default.

I have installed Qtdesigner4 from the Ubuntu software center. The plugin can be found separately at this [location](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQtdesignerplugins/1.1). My question is how can I install this plugin on my Ubuntu system for Qtdesigner. Note that the plugin is written in python, so I do not think pasting the plugin in the plugin folder will work.

I am using python 2.7.

I am a newbie so all details will help me.

Comment: [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org) is a standalone Python module. Install it with [`pip`](https://pip.pypa.io), just like any other module.

Comment: It is installed. However, I would like to utilize it as a widget in Qtdesigner as is automatically done with a standard installation of winpython on windows. It is not a standard widget in Qtdesigner from the Ubuntu software center, therefore I need to add it somehow.

Comment: Are you referring to [this](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/matplotlibwidget.html)? Then all you need to do is install [`PyQtGraph`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyqtgraph/0.9.10). Or perhaps you meant [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/winpython/pyqtdesignerplugins/ci/default/tree/matplotlibwidget.py)? A [single-word Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=matplotlibwidget) led me to those pages.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Qt designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-to-know.html)? It is a WYSIWYG gui builder. Winpython installs a custom drag and drop widget for it. A normal install of Qt designer from Ubuntu software center lacks this widget plugin. I can define a matplotwidget by using text coding, but I would like to use Qt designer to design the GUI. Installing modules does not fix the problem, as the problem deals with plugins for a GUI builder. I already have the necessary modules installed  for python to recognize the matplotlib widget, but not Qt designer.